# Renaming file using WinSCP

Tags: windows, batch-file, winscp

I've created a file names `upload.winscp`  with this content:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
rename cinta.dmp cinta_bck.dmp
exit
```

which I call from a bat file with this content

```
winscp.com /script="E:\upload.winscp" /log="E:\upload.winscp.log"
```

but when I run the bat file, the file is not renamed, neither the log created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script does not open any connection (what is also the reason that no log file is created).

You are missing [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open):

```
open ftp://username:password@example.com/
rename cinta.dmp cinta_bck.dmp
exit
```

---

*Or you misunderstood the purpose of WinSCP.*